# Can't load controller in thinkphp

Tags: php, phpstorm, thinkphp

I clicked 'Create Controller' button to build a new Controller like **indexController**. However, it can't load and error as:

> [image: error info] FILE:
>   F:\xampp\install\htdocs\ServerMonitorForWeb\ThinkPHP\Library\Think\App.class.php
>   　**LINE: 104**

What happened to my file or how to build a correct ThinkPHP controller in PhpStorm?

please!

Comment: You need to give our community more information as to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use reserved keywords as class names